# Get document's attachments via alfresco opencmis

Tags: alfresco

I want to get attached to object another object via OpenCmis from [alfresco](https://www.alfresco.com/).

To receive the object I use:

```
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.util.FileUtils;
AfrescoDocumentImpl doc = FileUtils.getObject("myID", session);
```

I also see that `doc` has `attached` aspect. I see that file does have attachment in `/share` web-gui.

**I want to get all attachments from this object:**
[image]

**How do I get this file from opencmis? Should I use some specific query?**
[image]

**The association in alfresco's table is the following:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's possible!

- You should use `session.getObject()` method
- You should pass Operation context with `IncludeRelationships.BOTH`

```java
OperationContextImpl op = new OperationContextImpl();
op.setIncludeRelationships(IncludeRelationships.BOTH);
AlfrescoDocumentImpl doc = session.getObject("id", op);
doc.getRelationships();
```